# Xamarin iOS: BackgroundTask, Do I need to set task object to invalid

Tags: ios, xamarin, task, background-task

I am using the background task. The task working fine but will force close at some point. I have test application and keep it open for whole afternoon, if I remove the background task I have in the code, the crash didn't happen.

After I looked closely, probably missing a line of code to assign the task object invalid.

```
var siteId = Settings.CurrentSiteId;
        if (siteId > 0 && !(new EntityBLL().IsInitial(siteId)))
        {
            var task = nint.MinValue;
            task = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask("bgEntityDownload", () =>
            {
                ServerEntity.TerminateAutoDownload(true);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(task);
                task = UIApplication.BackgroundTaskInvalid;

                completionHandler?.Invoke(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
            });

            AppLogger.Instance.AddLog(AppLogLevel.Information,
                                      nameof(TimerDownload),
                                      nameof(DownloadEntityFromServer),
                                      "Background download starts", "");

            var result = await ServerEntity.AutoDownload(siteId);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(task);
            task = UIApplication.BackgroundTaskInvalid;

            completionHandler?.Invoke(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
        }
```

The line here :

```
var result = await ServerEntity.AutoDownload(siteId);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(task);
            task = UIApplication.BackgroundTaskInvalid;
```

Is the line with task = UIApplicaition.BackgroundTaskInvalid is required after the work done.

Comment: It isn't "required".  You can use that value as a sentinel so that elsewhere in your code you know that the background task has been ended.  When running under Xcode you have infinite background execution time.  When run normally an app only has 180 seconds in the background before it is terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not required, but a good practice that allows a system to spend its resources on different processes. Your background task will be force terminated after 180 seconds.